# BlackBerry: is it possible to download application from a website (Over the Air) ?

Tags: blackberry, installation, over-the-air

I want would like to make my BlackBerry application available for download through a website using the BlackBerry browser. Is this possible?

Comment: http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A70_How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf

Comment: but is it required code sighning to deploy on our server also ?

Comment: Code signing is required if the application uses APIs that require code signing. These are all documented in the API Reference for each OS version.

Comment: Vivart you should answer questions as an answer, not a comment - that way you can get credit (upvotes) for it!

Comment: No worries, I've sorted that out for him :P

Comment: @YakubMoriswala, please accept the answer if you believe it has helped you.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to allow your BlackBerry application to be downloaded from a website:

**1.Over the Air distribution**

To allow users to install the application over the  air you will need to have a web server. On the web server you will need two files:

- Yourapplication.cod
- Yourapplication.jad

On your web server you will need to setup three MIME types:

- .jad files: text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
- .cod files: application/vnd.rim.cod
- .jar files (optional): application/java-archive

However, if the .cod file is larger than 64KB, it must be unzipped on the web server, otherwise you may get a "`907 invalid cod HTTP error 404`" error message. To do this, rename the .cod to .zip, then open the .zip file and place the file contents in the same folder on the web server alongside your .jad file. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788124/1943). Links to download your application should be to the .jad file.

**2.Using the BlackBerry Application Web Loader**

This is an ActiveX plugin that facilitates the download of the application. See the [developer documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Application%20Web%20Loader) for more information on this.

Reference:

Vivart's link: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Deploy-and-Distribute-Applications/ta-p/442794