# Multiple .debug and .cod files generated while building and signing my blackebrry app

Tags: blackberry

I am facing a peculiar problem when trying to build and sign my blackberry app with signing keys .The problem is its creating 2 debug files(sibling files) and also showing sibling .cod files when i am trying to sign the application with the keys but in the final deliverables folder there is only one .cod file .

However , earlier it was running fine and there was only one .debug and .cod file .
I cant understand what is the actually problem.

Any help or idea will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blackberry creates multiple .cod file when the .cod file size is more than 64 kb. In final folder what you are looking into may be the \deliverables\Standard\ [version no.] folder. There you can find a single .cod file. Actually this is not a .cod file. This is a zip file. Just rename to .ZIP. You can see multiple .cod files inside that. To publish to a web site you need multiple cod files and .jad file. But for blackberry app world submission that single .cod file is enough.

Comment: but the problem is when I upload that  .cod and .jad file on some server location and try to download it through Blackberry browser it some http error(.cod missing).

Comment: yes , when I extracted the .jar file ,I got two .cod files. Now which file should i upload on the server(only single .cod that was outside or two .cod that i got after extracting .jar file) actually earlier I got an error(1 .cod missing) when I uploaded .cod(the outside single one) and .jad file on the server. please suggest .

Comment: To deploy on web you need to put multiple cod file and jad file in the server and set the MIME type of JAD and COD in the server to the following.
JAD -> text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
COD -> application/vnd.rim.cod

You can get multiple cod files in two ways.
1. In the application folder you can find multiple install files in \deliverables\Web\ [version no] .From there take .jad file and all files with the extension of .cod file and deploy to the server.
2. From \deliverables\ Standard \ [version no] take.jad file and cod file. Rename the cod file to zip and get the multiple cod file.

Comment: Thanks Jomy, but thats not my issue now. I am asking that whether I should upload the single .cod file(along with .jad file) that is present in \deliverables\Web\ [version no]   or both .cod file that I got when i extracted .jar file present in \deliverables\Web\ [version no] .

Comment: If you want to deploy the BB installation files in a web server you have to deploy the multiple cod file. Not the single one. But there is one doubt. You said \deliverables\Web\ [version no] contains single cod file. This is not possible. In my system \deliverables\Web\ [version no] contains the multiple cod files and \deliverables\ Standard \ [version no] contains the single cod file. Can you confirm that?

Comment: yes Jomy, as you told when .cod file is > 64kb it becomes two. my .cod file is of 86kb and only single( shows two .cods when signing) but when i extracted the .jar file within \deliverables\Web\ [version no] there were two .cods files(38.7kb & 46.8 kb). Now while uploading the cod file on server which .cod should i use. The single one(of 86kb) or the two .cods(38.7 & 46.8kb) along with .jad.

Comment: Yes Multiple .cod files with .jad

Comment: @JomyJohn I took the .cod file from deliverables\Standard\[version no] ,converted it to zip and then extracted all .cod files then uploaded on server , now when i replace all .cod files, i cannot see any change in my app. **I am testing on simulator**. What i want know from you that if i replace all .cods in my app and app is upgraded, does that mean my new app changes will be applied and some new functionalities will be added/removed as per upgraded version and also UI will get changed. Sorry for the silly question but i am newbie in BB development. Thanks in advance.