# How to Upload COD file, RRC files and image files to BlackBerry AppWorld

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I am trying to upload a BB app to its App World. Everything I read makes a reference to upload a COD file or some COD files.

When you get to this point when submiting the app, it gives two choices to do the upload. One is file by file and the other is to upload a .ZIP file.

My problem is that when I sign my app, it generates a JAR file where are all my images and classes and .COD files and .CRB files (languages RRC files).

What I do is to convert this JAR to ZIP file and upload the app .ZIP way but it gives me an error because of the name of CRB files that now turns to have some strange characters. They come from a resources_en.rrc to a resources_úen.crb

I am doing something wrong but I can't figure it out. What is the right way to do this or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Eclipse:

The COD is in your workspace\ProjectName\deliverables\Standard\\YourProject.cod

All you need to upload the the App World is this COD file, don't need to do any converting of a JAR. Do, however, make sure you have signed the file by (in Eclipse) right clicking on the project -> BlackBerry -> Sign with Signature Tool

Comment: What I keep asking is about images of my app. I dont think they are in the .cod file and I'm worried about uploading this cod file without them.

Comment: What images? Image resources in the package that the app uses? Screenshots for App World?

Comment: Images the app uses, yes. I really need this help, thank you.

Comment: I accepted this as a correct answer so I could get the 2 extra points I needed to upvote your answer but I still need to make clear the resource images of my app point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as you have them in your res/ folder of the project they'll be added right along with it. Won't have to do anything special to get them in there!

Comment: So the images are inside the COD file? or do you mean I need to upload a complete ZIP file with COD file and res folder, etc?

Comment: They'll be included with the COD as long as they're in a folder in your project

Comment: This other [Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786477/multiple-debug-and-cod-files-generated-while-building-and-signing-my-blackebrry) is very useful to the context of this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The COD file is produced by RIM's compiler (rapc) and is the file that is signed. If you are using JDE for development it should be in the top level directory of your workspace. I'm not familiar with where Eclipse puts it.