# dilever my application to blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

what are the steps that need to deliver my app to blackberry device regardless bb version?

Note: my app has 6 files COD.

can I send direct link for these file to bb device and click on them sequentially to download my app to bb?

Comment: use the jad file along with the cod files. Then call that jad files url in your device's browser window.

Comment: so, I dont need third party to do that?

Comment: you asking about - How to upload app to App World ? Or How to run app in Devise ?

Comment: I need to send my app to bb device and no need to upload it to App Word.

Comment: sign your app , then call the url of the jad file in to the devise browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BlackBerry: is it possible to download application from a website (Over the Air) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825755/blackberry-is-it-possible-to-download-application-from-a-website-over-the-air)

Answer (score 1):

After you build your app, you publish the contents of the /OTAInstall folder on a Web Server.  Then load the URL to the *.JAD file in the BlackBerry browser and it will prompt you with a download page.

Note: you will need to setup MIME types on your Web Server for the *.jad and *.cod file types.

This is explained in detail this tutorial: [How to Deploy and Distribute Applications for BlackBerry (Java) Smartphones](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Deploy-and-Distribute-Applications/ta-p/442794).