# how to install blackberry app OTA

Tags: blackberry, installation, ota

I've just made my first Blackberry webworks app using PhoneGap. I want to install the app on a device, without connecting to the PC. The build generated an OTA folder containing 22 `.cod` files and 1 `.jad` file. How do I install this onto a device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BlackBerry: is it possible to download application from a website (Over the Air) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825755/blackberry-is-it-possible-to-download-application-from-a-website-over-the-air)

Comment: I have read this but I need to know which .cod files I need. It generated 22

Comment: **Please read the answer**.  You need all of them, of course.  How would an app function without all of its code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify [.htaccess file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) on your web-server, to recognize .jad and .cod files properly.

Add the following lines to your `.htaccess` file on your web-server.

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod cod
```

Then upload your cod files and jad file to your server.

After that navigate jad file location from your device browser.

**UPDATE:**

Upon compilation in OTA folder there are generated many cod files (in most cases).

To install your application wirelessly, you need .jad file and all of .cod files, located in OTA folder. Place jad and all of cod files into one folder on your web-server. And open jad-file location from your BlackBerry device browser. After that device will read jad file contents and will be able to install cod files to the device memory.

Comment: I'm sorry. What is a .htaccess file?

Comment: thanks i understand now. Ive never worked with Blackberry before